# Sending Message Using Wireless to GSM number

Tags: android, eclipse, messaging

Am working on an application in android that does the following. A part of the application is that the administrator can send universal notification to everyone registered to that application. I want this service to be in a way that the administrator uses his wireless to send the message to cellular gsm service. Now i was thinking it that is possible in android. How can i possibly do that?

Comment: What do you mean by Wireless over here.. Your question is not clear..

Comment: by wireless i mean using wifi. See the administrator can send the msg using wifi internet to the registered user's cellular number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A part of the application is that the administrator can send universal notification to everyone registered to that application. How can i possibly do that?`

You can use [`Google Cloud Messaging for Android`](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). It a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. You can send messages( or notifications) to all the Android users of your app. Each user would have a `registrationId` which would be unique for each user ( if you register them). That ID can be used to send messages to all your app users.

P.s: By wireless I am assuming internet.

Comment: yeah using the wifi. The application scope is simpler sir. I mean a just have some users registered by the administrator to the application! Nothing like my server!

Comment: Somewhere you have to maintain the list of 'registration ID's' of the users who has installed your app. If you don't want to use a 3rd party server then how do you plan to keep track of all the users who have installed the app or registered in the app?

Comment: Also, if the administrator just wants to send SMS to all the registered phone numbers, then why can't the administrator use some free SMS sending service on internet?

Comment: can u please be more descriptive?? free sms sending services?

Comment: If you would be taking there number after installing the app, then you need need to store it at some common server from where you can get all the numbers. If I assume that you already have phone numbers of all the users right, then you can use services VOIP of Google Messages to send them SMS(within Canada/US). For other places there are many VOIP service which provide you bulk sms's at cheap cost.

Comment: well ill store them in a database sir!

Comment: okay. Just curious to know where would be your database? On the app?

Comment: yup! database would be part of application!

Comment: fetch the records. place them as the recipients and send the msg! any suggestions from ur end??